# Simple iterator: error with std::count

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

this is a simple exercise. I'd like to write a custom iterator for a C-style array of characters all by myself: no boost. I think I'm halfway through, but I get an error when using `std::count`.

My iterator is this:

```
class myIterator : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>
{
    char *p;

public:

    // Definitions
    typedef typename std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>::reference reference;
    typedef typename std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>::pointer pointer;

    // Implementation
    myIterator(char* x) :p(x) { };
    myIterator(const myIterator& i) : p(i.p) { };
    myIterator& operator++() { ++p; return *this; };
    myIterator operator++(int) {myIterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp; };
    bool operator==(const myIterator& rhs) { return p == rhs.p; };
    bool operator!=(const myIterator& rhs) { return p != rhs.p; };
    char& operator*() { return *p; };
};
```

So, when I use the iterator in a `for` loop, it's great, it

```
for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
   std::cout << *it;
```

However, this gets a compile-time error:

```
std::cout << std::count(data.begin(), data.end(), '@') << std::endl;
```

For what it's worth, `data` is a super-simple class with a classic wrapping function for `begin()` and `end()` (*i.e.*, `return myIterator(address_);` and `return myIterator(address_ + size_);`).

What's the error is puzzling to me:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'count'
[...]
note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _InputIterator = myIterator, _Tp = char]: no type named 'difference_type' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<myIterator>'
count(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, const _Tp& __value_)
```

I am missing something here: I declared `difference_type` in the iterator.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deriving your class from `std::iterator` already defines `value_type`, `difference_type`, etc. So you shouldn't be defining them. Just make your inheritance public and remove those `typedef`s and it will work:

```
class myIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>
{
    char *p;

public:
    // Implementation
    myIterator(char* x) :p(x) { };
    // ......
};
```

Note that it's not necessary to remove the `typedef`s, but there is no reason to define them manually, `std::iterator` already does that.

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/C57fYG).

Comment: His solution will work, too, _if_ he repeats all of the typedefs.  He's forgotten one important one: `iterator_category`.

Comment: Damn, I hoped I could just use non-public inheritance. Do you think it's possible to avoid public?

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, you're right. However, he should either inherit std::iterator or write the typedefs, not both. Besides, that's the whole point of std::iterator.

Comment: @senseiwa why wouldn't you use public inheritance here?

Comment: @mfontanini no particular reason, I guess. I just wanted to use `std::iterator` as "implemented as", but I can live with "is-a", too.

Comment: @senseiwa Public inheritance is the simplest and most usual solution, but you can do it as you do, provided you repeat _all_ of the necessary typedef's.  You're missing `iterator_category`, and there's probably some sort of concept checking in the interface to `std::count`, which depends on `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category` to ensure that you don't try to instantiate the function with an output iterator.

Comment: @JamesKanze I am sorry for that, I looked at the code and saw *five* typedefs, but I actually wrote four. I think it's time for a pause :)

Comment: @mfontanini Or specialize `std::iterator_traits`.  (I just mention that for completeness' sake.  I've always just derived from `std::iterator`.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but the usual way of using
`std::iterator` is to inherit publicly from it.  Or to not use
it, and define all *five* of its typedefs.  I'd guess the reason
your code doesn't work is that the typedef for `iterator_category`
isn't accessible: if you don't derive publicly from
`std::iterator`, you have to provide it.

For what it's worth, there are three ways of making the
iterator type conform: inherit publicly from `std::iterator`,
declare the five typedefs (`value_type`, `difference_type`,
`pointer`, `reference` and `iterator_category`) directly in your
class (as public), or specialize `std::iterator_traits` on your
class (again, with the five typedefs).  The first is by far the
simplest and the most usual.